# Highlight only full words in CodeMirror

Tags: javascript, regex, codemirror

I'm trying to write a simple syntax highlighter for batch files for the `codemirror` editor. But I got stuck in highlighting the commands.
I want only full words to be highlighted. But in some cases, also parts of a variable name or a path are highlighted too.

This is how the highlighting looks like:

[image]

I use `\b(commands)\b` in my regular expression so that only full words are matched. But it doesn´t seem to work. Is it maybe a codemirror bug?

This is the code of the codemirror mode for simply highlighting the commands

```
CodeMirror.defineSimpleMode("batch", {
    start: [
        {   //commands
            regex: /\b(?:assoc|aux|break|call|cd|chcp|chdir|choice|cls|cmdextversion|color|com1|com2|com3|com4|com|con|copy|country|ctty|date|defined|del|dir|do|dpath|else|endlocal|erase|errorlevel|exist|exit|for|ftype|goto|if|in|loadfix|loadhigh|lpt|lpt1|lpt2|lpt3|lpt4|md|mkdir|move|not|nul|path|pause|popd|prn|prompt|pushd|rd|rename|ren|rmdir|setlocal|set|shift|start|time|title|type|verify|ver|vol)\b/i,
            token: "builtin"
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Please don't add images of code, add the code instead.

Comment: I have to add the image to show how the highlighting.

Comment: as far as i can see you want to match all words IF there is a whitespace after or whitspace or newline before

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution for this.

Instead of `\b(commands)\b` I use `(?:\s|^)(commands)(?:\s|$)` as john Smith suggested.
With this, only commands are highlighted with a whitespace or start of the line before the command and a whitespace or end of the line after the command.